# Control Errors in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, openlayers

When running OpenLayers map in IE9 I get a **"Unable to get value of the property 'displayClass': object is null or undefined"** error message.

After looking around at the problem, it seems that this line in the Openlayers.js file is the problem

```
this.controls=this.controls.concat(controls);
for(var i=0,len=controls.length;i<len;i++)
{var element=document.createElement("div");
element.className=controls[i].displayClass+"ItemInactive"; /* Problem here */
controls[i].panel_div=element;if(controls[i].title!="")
{controls[i].panel_div.title=controls[i].title;}
```

The script for my custom toolbar is:

```
OpenLayers.Control.CustomNavToolbar = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control.Panel,{
    initialize: function(options){
        OpenLayers.Control.Panel.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]);
        this.addControls([
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({displayClass: 'olControlNavigation', zoomBoxEnabled:false}),
            new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vlayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Point, {displayClass: 'olControlDrawPoint'}),
            new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vlayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {displayClass: 'olControlDrawPath'}),
            new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vlayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {displayClass: 'olControlDrawPolygon'}),
            new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({displayClass: 'olControlZoomBox', alwaysZoom:true}),
        ])
        this.displayClass = 'olControlCustomNavToolbar'
    },
    draw: function(){
        var div = OpenLayers.Control.Panel.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
        this.defaultControl = this.controls[0];
        return div;
    }
});
var panel = new OpenLayers.Control.CustomNavToolbar({div:OpenLayers.Util.getElement('panel')});
map.addControl(panel);
```

With CSS

```
    olControlCustomNavToolbar{
        float:left;
        right:0px;
        top:0px;
        width:160px;
        height:24px;
        margin:0px 6px 0px 0px;
    }   
    .olControlCustomNavToolbar div{
        float:right;
        height:24px;
        width:160px;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 6px;
    }
    .olControlCustomNavToolbar .olControlNavigationItemActive{
        width:24px !important;
        height:24px !important;
        margin:3px 0px 0px 6px !important;
        background-image: url("/OpenLayers-2.11/theme/default/img/pan_on.png")!important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .olControlCustomNavToolbar .olControlNavigationItemInactive{
        width:24px !important;
        height:24px !important;
        margin:3px 0px 0px 6px !important;
        background-image: url("/OpenLayers-2.11/theme/default/img/pan_off.png")!important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .olControlCustomNavToolbar .olControlDrawPointItemActive{
        width:24px !important;
        height:24px !important;
        margin:3px 0px 0px 6px !important;
        background-image: url("/OpenLayers-2.11/theme/default/img/draw_point_on.png")!important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .olControlCustomNavToolbar .olControlDrawPointItemInactive{
        width:24px !important;
        height:24px !important;
        margin:3px 0px 0px 6px !important;
        background-image: url("/OpenLayers-2.11/theme/default/img/draw_point_off.png")!important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .olControlCustomNavToolbar .olControlDrawPathItemActive{
        width:24px !important;
        height:24px !important;
        margin:3px 0px 0px 6px !important;
        background-image: url("/OpenLayers-2.11/theme/default/img/draw_line_on.png") !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .olControlCustomNavToolbar .olControlDrawPathItemInactive{
        width:24px !important;
        height:24px !important;
        margin:3px 0px 0px 6px !important;
        background-image: url("/OpenLayers-2.11/theme/default/img/draw_line_off.png") !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .olControlCustomNavToolbar .olControlDrawPolygonItemActive{
        width:24px !important;
        height:24px !important;
        margin:3px 0px 0px 6px !important;
        background-image: url("/OpenLayers-2.11/theme/default/img/draw_polygon_on.png") !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .olControlCustomNavToolbar .olControlDrawPolygonItemInactive{
        width:24px !important;
        height:24px !important;
        margin:3px 0px 0px 6px !important;
        background-image: url("/OpenLayers-2.11/theme/default/img/draw_polygon_off.png") !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .olControlCustomNavToolbar .olControlZoomBoxItemActive{
        width:24px !important;
        height:24px !important;
        margin:3px 0px 0px 6px !important;
        background-image: url("/OpenLayers-2.11/theme/default/img/drag-rectangle-off.png") !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .olControlCustomNavToolbar .olControlZoomBoxItemInactive{
        width:24px !important;
        height:24px !important;
        margin:3px 0px 0px 6px !important;
        background-image: url("/OpenLayers-2.11/theme/default/img/drag-rectangle-on.png") !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Could anyone give a little insight into what I am doing wrong here? Thank you

**EDIT:** FYI This works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. Only IE has this problem.

**EDIT:** Sorry I made a mistake I was running with IE7 Compatible; to rephrase after taking down the tag: **meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"** it works fine in IE9.

Alternately it **does NOT** work in IE7 or IE8 mode, if anyone has any ideas still looking to get this working in IE7 and IE8. Thanks, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In your `OpenLayers.Control.CustomNavToolbar` class, the `this.addControls` parameter array has a trailing comma.

Comment: Wow..should've caught that sooner.. Thanks! Please put as answer so I can close the question. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `OpenLayers.Control.CustomNavToolbar` class, the `this.addControls` parameter array has a trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

FYI IE9 will die if this is used:

map.layers[j].**proto**.CLASS_NAME

Use this instead and you're fine:

map.layers[j].CLASS_NAME